# How to create view of taxonomy terms and then once clicked on taxonomy term another view will be opened displaying all content having that term?

Tags: 8, views

I have a taxonomy called "Destination Type". There are 4 terms in it (Historical, Leisure, Wildlife,Cultural). 
I have created one content type called "Destination" with taxonomy field "destination_type".
Now I want to create a view of taxonomy "destination type" which is I am able to create. Once user click on any of the term in that view say Historical, then the next view should open displaying the list of all destinations with destination type as historical.

This is how I want the result same as "Jump right in, Things to do" in http://www.gotobermuda.com/

I am stuck here. Please help me out with this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I get it working. It was not that hard :)

First I create the view of taxonomy term. In that view I add contextual filter "Taxonomy term : term ID".

And in the next view I add contextual filter "Content: content_type_name"

Thats it. Got the desired result.